# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' while on loop

Tags: python, json, dictionary, attributeerror

I know this is an attribute error that is caused because of trying to access a property that is not defined on the

So basically I am parsing a JSON response returned by an API.

the response looks like this.

```
{
    "someProperty": {
         "value": 123
     }
},
{
    "someProperty":null
},
```

which I am looping the `x = response.json()` object and trying to access as,

```
x.get('someProperty', {}).pop('value', 0)
```

which works on the testing with the interpreter manually

```
In[2]: x = {1:2, 2:34}
In[3]: x.get('someProperty', {}).pop('value', 0)
Out[3]: 0
```

but when accessed the same inside a class function, it raises attribute error. What am I doing wrong?

**The error is only raised when the method is called progmatically when the value of `someProperty` is null.**

### update

it is how I am using inside a class.

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.value = kwargs.get('someProperty', {}).pop('value', 0)

    def save():
        pass
```

Now the usage,

```
x = response.json()
for num, i in enumerate(x):
    j = SomeClass(**i)
    j.save()
```

Comment: Show *exactly* how you are using this "inside a class function".

Comment: wait let me update code

Comment: `x` can't be set to a single dictionary; you have multiple dictionaries so *at the very least* `x` would be a list. Your test is also flawed, your input JSON shows that you can easily have a dictionary that would have `{'someProperty': None}`, at which point `x.get('someProperty', {})` returns `None` and that object has no `.pop()` method.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated the code, this command `{}.get(1, 0)` outputs `0`, so how come `{}` does not have `.get()` method? can you say if the updated usage show how `{}` is interpreted as `None` in the given code?

Comment: @Marty: You are using the wrong dictionary. `{1: None}.get(1, 0)` outputs `None`.

Comment: @Marty: your *key exists*, and it's value is `None`. That's a different case from the key not existing.

Comment: @Marty: you seem to think that setting the value to `None` (or `null` in JSON) removes the key altogether, or that setting the value to `None` makes `dict.get()` ignore the key. That's not how it works. If the key is present and the value it references is `None`, then that is what is returned, not the default value for `dict.get()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting the case where `someProperty` exists, but is set to `None`. You included that case in your input JSON:

```
{
    "someProperty":null
}
```

Here the key *exists*, and its value is set to `None` (the Python equivalent for `null` in JSON). That value is then returned by `dict.get()`, and `None` doesn't have a `.pop()` method.

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"someProperty": null}')
{'someProperty': None}
>>> x = json.loads('{"someProperty": null}')
>>> print(x.get("someProperty", 'default ignored, there is a value!'))
None
```

`dict.get()` only returns the default if the key does not exist. In the above example, `"someProperty"` exists, so it's value is returned.

I'd replace any falsey value with an empty dictionary:

```
# value could be None, or key could be missing; replace both with {}
property = kwargs.get('someProperty') or {}  
self.value = property.pop('value', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. You opened my eyes!! ;)